# Using ARM templates is three a way of creating a storage account container using the access keys of the storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Ive just started on a project where the arm templates were working with no issues. Recently however one of the templates which creates a storage account and container has stopped working.
The issue is that access is denied when creating the blob container.

Is there a way using ARM template to specify the container creation using the storage account access key?

Comment: is there any firewall rule / network restriction?